# The load of css or jquery file

Tags: css, performance

I don't know the keyword to find the answer of my question in google, so I put my question here. If I use bootstrap css or any frameworks css, and I don't implement all the classes or the ids in my html file maybe only a half of it, is it still gonna load all the css ? if it yes, so my website will load longer.
and what about jquery ?

Comment: Yes, it will load all the framework files regardless of how much you use.

Comment: Its both not more than 100kb and I do not feel it could affect the performance. Try the minified version!! Use cloudfare, it has auto minify on fly option!! Whats the size of your site?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't even possible to deliberately load only part of a file. That's all or nothing. However, many frameworks allow you to customize it so you only use the parts you need. You can [customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and remove CSS classes, components, and JavaScript you know you aren't going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website will always download whole library.
There is, however, a possible way to overcome loading delay. You have to use CDN (Content Delivery Network), just like that (for twitter):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When You do that, there is a big chance that user have previously visited some websites using the very same libraries that You use, and has bootstrap, jquery or other library already cached in his memory (the more popular library, the bigger chance is).

Comment: The caching will only help if the site implements the library or framework via a CDN. Since caching is implemented at the domain level (in most cases), if you serve your own copies rather than use a CDN, your users will be forced to download the files the first time they visit.

Comment: @War10ck, good point, haven't event thought of hosting libs oneself. I'll edit the post